# how to add an event listener to a state in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to scroll to the end of my `FlatList` when the state of `messages` changes. Currently I'm using `this.refs.flatList.scrollToEnd();` after waiting a bit, which works OK. What I want to do is add an event listener to the `messages` state so that when the list is changed in any way it will scroll to the end of the list. I tried

```
componentDidMount(){
        this.state.messages.addEventListener('change', this._handleNewMessage);
}
```

but it doesn't work. Does anyone know a way I can achieve this?

Comment: _"when the list is changed in any way"_ what do you mean by any way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be what the lifecycle method [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) is for:

> `componentDidUpdate()` is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated. ...

Naturally, you have to ensure that `this.state.messages` is only changed via `setState`—but that was already true, using `componentDidUpdate` doesn't change that.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.refs.flatList.scrollToEnd();
}
```